what if the patent examiner finds the specifications to be unclear?
If the patent examine cannot understand the specifications of your invention in the patent application, are you allowed to modify the specifications?
If so, what are the rules and limits to do so?

The rule is no new matter. You can fix formatting and grammatical mistakes and also technical errors that are obvious mistakes, particularly if the correction is uniquely obvious. You can bring in text and figures from priority documents with some limitations. Figures can be redrawn to make them easier to see without adding new matter.
It is possible to refer them to textbooks and reference works to understand terms you use. An interview either telephonically or in person might be able to clear up misunderstandings.
I have never tried this but it might be possible to get and submit an affidavit from someone “skilled in the art” stating that your description would be clear to a person in the field and would have the following meaning.
